# Maximum refresh rate with HDMI 1.4 and 3440x1440 resolution

Tags: hdmi, resolution, refresh-rate

I want to buy new gaming monitor and I'm not sure about resolution, becuase I'm limited to HDMI in version 1.4.

I know, I can run 2560x1440@60Hz (16:9), but what about 3440x1440@60Hz (21:9)? According to [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ultrawidemasterrace/comments/8ptkm7/aw3418dw_3440x1440_60hz_over_hdmi/), it can handle 3440x1440@50Hz at max. Is it true?

Comment: That depends entirely on what formats the display’s input can take. Look at its specs.

Comment: When I buy 3440x1440 monitor with 60Hz refresh rate, it will obviously support 3440x1440@60Hz... Or am i missing something? :-)

Comment: Yes. It might not support that resolution over HDMI. Instead, you’d have to use DisplayPort. I have an older 1440p display that only supports 1080p over HDMI.

Comment: I just looked at specs of some monitors and found nothing about supported display modes. Still think, bottleneck is in HDMI version. So when both display and laptop (in my case) will have HDMI 1.4 (or above), it is really just about maximum bandwidth...

Comment: I agree that you really need DisplayPort. Depending on the hardware, you might even find yourself with less than 50Hz.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I was playing with custom resolutions on friend's 4K monitor and it seems, that 3440x1440@56Hz is limit for my HDMI cable...

[image]

Comment: But did it work with a better HDMI cable to get 3440x1440@60Hz? As far as I know, most HDMI cables support even 4K (which is more than that) and then there are the new HDMI 2.1 cables that support even 8K.
Confused because I am stuck with the same problem, only getting 30Hz.

Comment: This is quite an old question, but if I remember correctly, better cable did not help. But I'm not sure, why the 60 Hz was not possible. According to [this tool](https://linustechtips.com/topic/729232-guide-to-display-cables-adapters-v2/?section=calc&H=3840&V=2160&F=240&calculations=show&formulas=show), even 65 Hz should be possible.

But maybe, you are actually trying to use 3840x2160@60Hz.  In that case, limit is 39 Hz and only with custom preset...

Comment: Indeed :) same problem years later. I found out that my notebook only has a HDMI 1.4 port (although it has a HDMI 2.0 capable GPU) and with help of the custom resolution utility CRU on Windows and autorandr on Linux I am, at least, able to get 56 Hz permanently at 3440x1440.